# Concatenating Columns

Tags: excel, concatenation, highlight, vba

So I am trying to concatenate Column A cells with Column C cells, but the problem is that I only want to concatenate the two columns if and only if the column C cell is highlighted. Some cells in column C are highlighted (every other but it may not be like that all of the time). So say we start from A2 and C2, if C2 is highlighted then we concatenate A2 with C2 and leave the change in C2. Then move on to the next row and if C3 is not highlighted then we skip that and check if C4 is highlighted. If C4 data is highlighted then we concatenate A4 with C4. So we just continue that as a loop onto the last row that has information.

So far this is what I have:

```
Sub ConcatAandC()

Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 1) & "- " & Cells(i, 3)
Next i

End Sub
```

As you can see, this concatenates all of the rows. I am only targeting the rows where Column C cells are highlighted.

My second problem is that since Column A consist of dates, I only want the month and day to show up. I tried to just change the formatting of Column A hoping that when it copies the date from column A to column C it'll only show the month and the day but unfortunately it wasn't that simple.  For instance, Cell A2 has 8/1/2014, when it concatenates with C2 it'll only be 8/1 and Cell C data. I also thought about creating a code where it scans through column C to search for "/2014" and deletes it but I have no idea where to start with that.

So I would greatly appreciate it if someone can give me ideas on how to do this. I am also new to VBA so please bear with me!

Comment: What do you mean by `Highlighted`? i.e selected? Has background color?

Comment: @SiddharthRout the entire cell is yellow so the background color

Comment: One last question. Are these color because of conditional formatting or normal cell background color?

Comment: It's a normal cell background color @SiddharthRout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will loop through Column C and check if the cell has Yellow color and if it does then it will concatenate it.

```
Sub ConcatAandC()
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            '~~> Check If cell in Col C is yellow
            If .Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = 65535 Then _
            .Range("C" & i).Value = Format(.Range("A" & i).Value, "MM/DD") & _
                                    " - " & .Range("C" & i).Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not going to post a separate answer but you may want to edit the answer based on OP's comment below the question? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout it is really a coincidence, I wrote a code when you added a comment. Did not mean to "steal" your anwser. I am far far less experienced than you :) ...and my edit was due to not closed `if statement`

Comment: @lowak thank you for commenting! but my problem with it is that since Column A consist of dates I only need the month and the day.  So it changes.. it could be 8/1 or 8/31 and the 8/31 would be cut off to 8/3

Comment: I know you didn't mean to steal it :) I am just saying that you may want to edit your answer to incorporate OP's request so that I don't have to post an exact answer :) No point having multiple answers stating the same thing...

Comment: @SiddharthRout there are two options: first, it is hard day due to weather changes in my area and I do not actually know what do you want from me or second, you created a strange request I cannot understand (may also be an effect of the weather problem ;). If you could tell me more excacly what do you want me to add to my awnser I would be thankful (or please edit it on your own?).

Comment: @lowak your code is fine just the fact that it's copying the data based on the substring. I stated in the second part of the question that the first column consist of dates. So it can be 8/3/2014(8 char) or 8/31/2014(9 char). So when I changed the Mid(Cells(i, 1), 1, 4) & "- " & Cells(i, 3), it shows me "8/1/" for 8/1/2014 and "8/31" for 8/31/2014. I don't want the "/" for the 8/1 so the dates can look different depending on the date. I have no idea how to edit that part since it's just changing the numbers within that code and since im new, I don't really know what to add to fix that.

Comment: @user3914368 yes I understand so I wanted to know if your cells in column A are dates or values. Try updated code.

Comment: @lowak they are dates and nothing shows up when I run that code :(

Comment: I have edited it and if you do not like it, you can reverse the edits :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout not really, it should be your anwser so I am fine with edit. I always learn a lot from your anwsers. Thanks :)

Comment: + 1 All's well that ends well :)

Comment: @user3914368 trying my best, not as good as SiddharthRout but still :)